# How can I show unicode of more than one byte chars in java

Tags: java, unicode, emoji

I have to show unicode of input characters 
for example A -> 65
but what should I do for characters like emojis? 
 -> 125814

Comment: `"".toCodePoints().forEach(System.out::println)` or `"".codePointAt(0)` or `Character.codePointAt("", 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to output the codepoint of any character:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Test
{
    public static int getCodePoint(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        byte[] a = s.getBytes("UTF-32BE");
        return ((a[1] & 0xFF) << 16) + ((a[2] & 0xFF) << 8) + (a[3] & 0xFF);
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        System.out.println(getCodePoint("A")); // 65
        System.out.println(getCodePoint("")); // 128514
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may work, it is not a good solution since Java already provides `Character.codePointAt()` and `String.codePointAt()`, as mentioned in a comment to the question.

Comment: @skomisa You're right, I thought that codePointAt() was not supporting surrogate pairs, but it turns out it does.